# upload CoreData into CollectionViewCell and configure

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uikit

I've two view controllers. on the first one I've Collection View and on the other one I have `text field`s  to upload to `CoreData`, after uploading to `CoreData` I want those fields to be transferred into `CollectionViewCell` but I can't do the configuration of `CollectionViewCell` also everytime I click `addMonacemebi` to add fields data into CoreData xCode returns an error that those fields are `nil`.

p.s. I reload `CollectionView` with `NotificationCenter`.
if you have any addition question about the code please let me know in the comment secion

any solution will be appericated <3

```swift
//second view controller to upload textfields data into coredata with button
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
var monacemebi = [StatiaList]()
class AddViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var satauriField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var statiaField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var janriField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var dateField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var authorField: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
    public var statiebi = [StatiaList]()
    func getAllItems(){
        do {
            statiebi = try context.fetch(StatiaList.fetchRequest())
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                //self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        } catch {
            
        }
    }
    func createItem(satauri: String,avtori: String, janri:String,statia:String){
        let newItem = StatiaList(context: context)
        newItem.avtori = avtori
        newItem.janri = janri
        newItem.satauri = satauri
        newItem.statia = statia
        newItem.tarighi = Date()
        
        do {
            try context.save()
            getAllItems()
        } catch {
            
        }
    }
    @IBAction func addMonacemebi(_ sender: Any) {
        createItem(satauri: self.satauriField.text!, avtori: self.authorField.text!, janri: self.janriField.text!, statia: self.statiaField.text!)
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("load"), object: nil)
        
    }
}
//first view controllers where collectionview is located
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(loadList(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "load"), object: nil)
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return statiebi.count
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let statia = statiebi[indexPath.row]
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        
        cell.config(with: statia)
        cell.backgroundColor = .gray
        cell.myLabel.textColor = .white
        
        
        return cell
    }
//collectionviewcell
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var janri: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var author: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var statia: UILabel!
    func config(with: StatiaList){
        self.statia = statiebi
    }
}

// automatically generated CoreData from xCode
import Foundation
import CoreData


extension StatiaList {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<StatiaList> {
        return NSFetchRequest<StatiaList>(entityName: "StatiaList")
    }

    @NSManaged public var satauri: String?
    @NSManaged public var tarighi: Date?
    @NSManaged public var avtori: String?
    @NSManaged public var janri: String?
    @NSManaged public var statia: String?

}

extension StatiaList : Identifiable {

}
```

Comment: What is statiebi on the first view controllers where collectionview is located?

Comment: Anyway, getAllItems() must be in the viewController with collectionView, AddViewController should Add data and nothing more. After you add data, you return to collection view, fetch data, store it in array somewhere in FirstViewController and call collectionView.reloadData()